# Filtering based on value from multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am working on Datatable filtering. I an getting values from multiple text boxes and trying to apply "contains" filter. Below is my approach.

```
var counter2 = 2;
$('#selectionIN').on('change', function () {
  fil3 = $(this).val();
});
$("#addButton2").click(function () {
  if(counter2>10){
    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
    return false;
  }
  var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div'))
  .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);

  newTextBoxDiv2.after().html('<label>Item Name #'+ counter2 + ' : </label>' +
                              '<input type="text" name="textbox2' + counter2 +
                              '" id="textbox2' + counter2 + '" value="" >');

  newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup2");
  counter2++;
});

$("#removeButton2").click(function () {
  if(counter2==2){
    return false;
  }
  counter2--;
  $("#TextBoxDiv2" + counter2).remove();
});

$("#getButtonValue2").click(function () {
  var msg2 = '';
  for(i=1; i<counter2; i++){
    msg2 +=  $('#textbox2' + i).val();
    msg2 +="|";
  }
  msg2=msg2.slice(0, -1);       
  if(fil3=="exact"){
    var patt = msg2.replace(/[\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$-]/g, "\\$&");    //escape regex chars except "|"
    patt = patt.replace(/ /g, "\\\s");  //change space to "\s" to make fnFilter works
    if (patt)
      patt = "^(" + patt + ")$";  //enclose with parentheses only when pattern is not empty

    console.log(patt);
    $("#testTable").dataTable().fnFilter(patt, 1, true);
    console.log(msg2);
  }
  else if(fil3=="Begin"){
    $('#testTable').dataTable().fnFilter("^" + msg2 + "$", 1, true);
    console.log(msg2);
  }
  else if(fil3=="contains"){
    $('#testTable').dataTable().fnFilter("^.*" + msg2 + ".*$", 1, true);
    console.log(msg2);
  }
  else{
    $("#testTable").dataTable().fnFilter(msg2, 1, true);//Exact value, column, reg*/
    console.log(msg2);
  } 
});
```

Now the problem is, It is filtering the rows containing the mentioned in first textbox and for second textbox it filters only rows that begin with given value. Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I was using before

```
else if(fil3=="contains"){
   $('#testTable').dataTable().fnFilter("^.*" + msg2 + ".*$", 1, true);
   console.log(msg2);
}
```

Now included the value to be matched inside the bracket as below:

```
$('#testTable').dataTable().fnFilter("^.*(" + msg2 + ").*$", 1, true);
```